# mapDispatchToProps doesn't work: Uncaught TypeError: _this.props.addCountdown is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build my first app and I'm stuck. I have a form component which should send object via onSubmit handler.

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.onSubmit({
            title: this.state.title,
            category: this.state.category,
            releaseDate: this.state.releaseDate.valueOf(),
            description: this.state.description
        });
    };
```

My addCountdown seems to receive everything correctly when function with console.log(countdown) is added to this.onSubmit() but when I try to connect it with my addCountdown action it shows Uncaught TypeError: _this.props.addCountdown is not a function.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import CountdownForm from './CountdownForm';
import { addCountdown } from '../actions/countdowns';

export class AddCountdownItem extends React.Component {
    onSubmit = (countdown) => {
        this.props.addCountdown(countdown);
        this.props.history.push('/');
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Add countdown</h1>
                <CountdownForm onSubmit={this.onSubmit} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    addCountdown: (countdown) => dispatch(addCountdown(countdown))
});

export default connect(undefined, mapDispatchToProps)(AddCountdownItem);
```

And here the action:

```
export const addCountdown = (
    {
      title = '',
      category = '',
      releaseDate = 0,
      description = ''
    } = {}
  ) => ({
    type: 'ADD_COUNTDOWN',
    countdown: {
      title,
      category,
      releaseDate,
      description
    }
  });
```

[image: console.log(this.props)]

Added sandbox. Its my first time using it so hopefully its done correctly. Sorry for a mess but im just starting.

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Lukasz-Gumpert/React-boilerplate

[image: second image]

Comment: what does the result of `console.log(props)` in render show?

Comment: when added bellow render it shows: Uncaught ReferenceError: props is not defined

Comment: Dear @Lukas, welcome to Stack Overflow, I think your issue comes from a typo mistake. if you can please upload your re-production issue on CodeSandBox. the issues like your issue should be analyzed on a project.

Comment: @AmerllicA where do you see a typo?

Comment: props is not defined because he meant this.props

Comment: sorry yes `console.log(this.props)`, apologies

Comment: @Lukas, I don't see a typo, I just guess it exists in the countdowns.js file. or somewhere else. but please `console.log(this.props)` and insert the screenshot in your post. or leave a CodeSandBox project.

Comment: Do other Redux actions in your application work properly?

Comment: Your image didn't help much, because you're expanding props.history.. i think your redux isn't setup properly or something...

Comment: i just started my app so this is my first action i try to wire. I will try to post to CodeSandBox but i never used it so give me a moment :) Meanwhile i posted screenshot of this.props above

Comment: @Lukas, I leave an upvote for your try buddy, I wait for your CodeSandBox version.

Comment: added sandbox and will upload next screen of props https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Lukasz-Gumpert/React-boilerplate

Comment: @Lukas, I can't believe it. Do you post your whole project to the CodeSandBox?!! for such these cases you should make a re-production of your project to simulate the error and then post the re-production on the air. I believe **`i.brod`** is a good man who write your whole project and passes the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Looked at your code and found the problem...you were using the un-connected AddCountdownItem component. In your AppRouter file, import it this way:

```
import  AddCountdownItem  from '../components/AddCountdownItem';
```

This imports the **default export**, which in your case is the component connected to redux. Now the props are available.

Answer (score -1):

You are loosing the context(`this`) when you pass the function as a reference. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback).

To fix your issue change:

```
 <CountdownForm onSubmit={this.onSubmit} />
```

to

```
 <CountdownForm onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)} />
```

Comment: But he is using arrow functions.

Comment: He is using arrow function. it means he is using babel plugin for class properties that transform arrow functions in the class and the `this` object bind by default. your answer is true but not for this version.

Comment: True, I missed that

Comment: Also it would be a different error not `_this.props.addCountdown` is not a function. it would read cannot access `addCountdown` of `undefined`